# Cannot remove file or Directory

Tags: solaris

I have root on the server in question.
OS: Solaris 10 sparc

When I ls the audit_old directory I get:
root@z10801 audit_old # ls
qm2_ora_24871_1c.aud.gz

ls -al results in:
root@z10801 audit_old # ls -al
total 250658
drwxr-x---   2 oraqm2   dba      128261632 Mar  6 21:55 .
drwxr-x---  17 oraqm2   dba          512 Mar  6 20:55 ..

rm gives me:
root@z10801 audit_old # rm qm2_ora_24871_1c.aud.gz
qm2_ora_24871_1c.aud.gz: No such file or directory

rm -rf the dir gives me:
root@z10801 rdbms # rm -rf audit_old/
rm: Unable to remove directory audit_old/: File exists

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This behavior may be due to a file currently open by a separate process.
Even though you have removed it, the file is not truly removed by the OS until the process closes the file.

Try to find out the process that has the file open by using:

$ fuser .

In the directory which has the problem.

This command will print the process Id's which have files currently in use.

Comment: The pid for the file keeps changing. How do I find the parent process?